# не изменяется значение max_allowed_packet mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

Добрый день!
Надо экспортировать БД mysql 5.7.20 с большими BLOB-полями. Естественно, требуется увеличить max_allowed_packet.
Экспортировать пытаюсь через Workbench 6.3. Так вот, значение переменной max_allowed_packet меняется только в секции [mysqld]. Перерыв интернет, узнал, что надо поменять и на клиенте и на сервере. Но Workbench-ем в других секциях не меняется (т.е. меняется, но не запоминается - перехожу из одной секции в другую например из [mysql] в [mysqld] и значение в [mysql] сбрасывается на дефольтное).
    В my.ini прописал в разных секциях [mysql] [mysqld] [mysqldump] свои значения max_allowed_packet. Но результата нет. Измененные значения всё равно видит только в [mysqld].
    Пытался через командную строку, но там вообще ничего не происходит. Появляется стрелочка -> и всё. Кстати, что она означает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `max_allowed_packed` или `max_allowed_packet`?

Comment: И еще что значит появляется строчка `->` и все? Может картинку прикрепите к вопросу? И скажете что конкретно делаете в командной строке?

Comment: Знаю, что не актуально. Вероятно у тебя есть DT_IMAGE в переносимых данных